# How to make a canvas white after drawing?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am drawing on the canvas properly and saving it into a bitmap.
However, I want to reset the canvas to white by clicking a button.

Here is my code:

```
public class Canvas extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Path path;
    boolean cc = false;

public Canvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint = new Paint();
    path = new Path();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!cc) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        cc = false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float xPos = event.getX();
    float yPos = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}


public void clear() {
    cc = true;
    invalidate();
}
```

my clear() function set cc to "true" then invalidate() calls the onDraw() function. But it seems that "cc" is not recognized inside the onDraw() or it has always the same value inside.
I tried the path.reset() with no result.

calling clear() does not return any error.

Answer (score 0):

To clear all your canvas use this:

```
     Paint transparent = new Paint();
     transparent.setAlpha(0);
```

Update:

Add this line in your button onclick():

canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

And remove it from the draw function.

Comment: Doing this doesn't work: public void clear() {
        paint.setAlpha(0);
        invalidate();
    }

Comment: Y hv u added invalidate() there?

Comment: Yes but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you'd want the `path` to get cleared too when your `clear()` method is called, so do that, then use the fact that the `path` is empty to clear the canvas.

```
public void clear() {
    path.reset();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (path.isEmpty()) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

That entirely eliminates the `cc` field.

Comment: In the activity class, I have a button which calls the method clear() of the canvas. Doing exactly what you said and clicking the button does not clear the canvas. Do I need to invalidate the canvas in the activity class by its android:id ?